# data.table CJ with string as input

Tags: r, data.table

How can the CJ-command be run with string as input? The following MNWE illustrates what is needed:

```
library(data.table)
# This is the desired output (when needed.cols==2)
dt.wanted <- CJ(X.1=c(1L, 2L), X.2=c(1L, 2L))
# Here is an example with needed.cols as variable
needed.cols <- 2L
use.text <- paste0("X.", 1L:needed.cols, "=c(1L, 2L)", collapse=", ")
# Here are some failing attempts
dt.fail <- CJ(use.text)
dt.fail <- CJ(eval(use.text))
dt.fail <- CJ(get(use.text))
```

So it is the use.text I want to make scriptable (because it varies, not only with needed.cols).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for a function to pass a list of arguments into `...` of a function. You can do it using `do.call` as follows:

```
do.call(CJ, eval(parse(text=paste0("list(",use.text,")"))))
```

Hope that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

The `get`-function is the standard way of promoting a character value to a true R name value.

Is this what you want:

```
col.wanted =2
dt.wanted[ , get(paste0("X.", col.wanted) )]
#[1] 1 2 1 2
```

Getting multiple columns based on evaluation of a more complex expression might require somewhat more baroque efforts:

```
> use.text <- paste0("list(", paste0("X.", 1L:needed.cols, collapse=", "),")")
> use.text
[1] "list(X.1, X.2)"
> dt.wanted[ , eval(use.text)]
[1] "list(X.1, X.2)"
> dt.wanted[ , parse(text=use.text)]
expression(list(X.1, X.2))

> dt.wanted[ , eval(parse(text=use.text))]
   X.1 X.2
1:   1   1
2:   1   2
3:   2   1
4:   2   2
```